# Equation involving difference of beta CDFs

Tags: probability, special-functions, beta-function

Consider the expression
$$I_{p}(\alpha,\beta+1) - I_{p}(\alpha+1,\beta) = c$$
where $I_p(a,b)$ is the [regularized incomplete beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function#Incomplete_beta_function).

**Question:** Given $\alpha,\beta,$ and $c>0$, what is $p$?

---

**Attempt:** I need to invert the CDF's, but the problem is the arguments of the CDFs are not the same. I'm not sure how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

Using the inductive property

$$I_p(\alpha,\beta+1)=I_p(\alpha,\beta)+\frac{p^{\alpha}(1-p)^{\beta}}{\beta\,B(\alpha,\beta)}$$

$$I_p(\alpha+1,\beta)=I_p(\alpha,\beta)-\frac{p^{\alpha}(1-p)^{\beta}}{\alpha\,B(\alpha,\beta)}$$

It is obtained:

$$p^{\alpha}\,(1-p)^{\beta}=c\,(\frac{1}{\alpha}+\frac{1}{\beta})\,B(\alpha,\beta)\:$$

From here there is no general solution in a closed form  $\forall\,\alpha$,$\beta$ but last equation is very easy to solve numerically